# how to perform the post object operation in amazon s3 web services using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to perform the `post object` operation against Amazon's S3 web service. For this we need to use HTML forms to upload the file into S3.

Can any one help me to perform this operation?. I have read the documentation of Amazon S3. I have understood the concept but I am unable to perform the operation programmatically.

Thanks,
Purna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) contains code which will make HTTP POST uploads to S3 with a signed policy. The SDK sends the form post over the wire for you, but you could adapt the code to write HTML documents instead.

First: Here's the relevant code:

- [S3PostUploadRequest.cs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/Util/S3PostUploadRequest.cs)
- [S3PostUploadSignedPolicy.cs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/Util/S3PostUploadSignedPolicy.cs)
- The [PostUpload](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/Util/AmazonS3Util.Operations.cs#L664) method.

There is also a [blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxEWY3WMAPLUGZ/-Uploading-to-Amazon-S3-with-HTTP-span-class-matches-POST-span-using-the-AWS-SDK) which shows how to use these utilities in a C# program.